# VBA - Count in For Loop using If Statement

Tags: excel, vba

Objective of the code is to count the number of rows that meet three conditions and output the count to populate in a particular cell.

Input data:

[image]

The 3 conditions are:

1. Column A of the row must contain a date field
2. Column B of the row must be equal to "B"
3. Column A of the row must have red font

I have the following code, but it seems to not pick up the last condition properly. I am expecting to see 1 as an output but seeing 0:

```
Sub code()
    
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Cells(2, "D").Value = "Count"
    Count = 0
    For i = 2 To lrow
      If IsDate(Cells(i, "A").Value) = True And Cells(i, "B").Value = "B" And Cells(i, "A").Font.Color = -16776961 Then
      Count = Count + 1
      End If
    Next i

    Cells(2, "E").Value = Count
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try with `Font.Color =rgb(255,0,0)`?

Comment: Did you try in the Immediate window (VB Editor -> View) to `Print Cells(5, "A").Font.Color` to check if you are matching with the correct value?

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub test1()
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
    Do Until IsEmpty(cl)
        cnt = cnt - (IsDate(cl.Value) And cl.Offset(0, 1) = "B" And cl.Font.Color = vbRed)
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1)
    Loop
    Debug.Print "Matches = " & cnt
End Sub
```

**Input:**
[image]

**Output:**

```
Matches = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Cells(2, "D").Value = "Count"
    Count = 0
    For i = 2 To lrow
      If IsDate(Cells(i, "A").Value) = True And Cells(i, "B").Value = "B" And Cells(i, "A").Font.Color = vbRed Then
      Count = Count + 1
      End If
    Next i

    Cells(2, "E").Value = Count
```

Comment: 1. Would help better to only include code that changed. 2. It is OK if the OP referred to this kind of red, otherwise still no match, and the value needs to be tested as I commented above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the color index as below:

`.Font.ColorIndex = 3` which is red [enter link description here][1] They give more options and details on working with font colors.

```
Sub code()
    
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Cells(2, "D").Value = "Count"
    Count = 0
    For i = 2 To lrow
      If IsDate(Cells(i, "A").Value) = True And Cells(i, "B").Value = "B" And Cells(i, "A").Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
      Count = Count + 1
      End If
    Next i

    Cells(2, "E").Value = Count
    
End Sub


  [1]: https://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-color-code-list/
```

Comment: 1. Would help better to only include code that changed. 2. It is OK if the OP referred to this kind of red, otherwise still no match, and the value needs to be tested as I commented above.

Comment: I mentioned at the top of my answer the section that got changed and showed it implemented in their code. I'm also assuming the 'red' they're using is the standard red that's selected by default in excel, but also provided a link to a source that provides other options for working with colors, just in case it was a different red. Testing should be the given, I tested this and it worked with the standard red.